# Flip two fair coins. Given that one is "tail," what is the probability that the other has a "head"?

Tags: probability

Here's what I already did-

List of possible outcomes:

```
1. HH
2. HT
3. TH
4. TT
```

Since we already know that one must be a tail, `HH` will not be included/eliminated.

Hence, possible outcomes:

```
 1. HT
 2. TH
 3. TT
```

Hence, the answer is 2/3.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: The probability we seek is one head and the other tail hence the event is {ht,th}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean. "Given that one is tails": do you mean:

- "given that this specific one is tails" (in which case the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$), or
- "given that at least one is tails" (in which case you're correct and it's $\frac{2}{3}$), or
- "given that exactly one is tails" (in which case it's $1$, of course)?

You might like to look up the Boy or Girl paradox, by the way.

Comment: It should be "given at least one is tails". I just needed the confirmation. Thanks so much for confirming it! :)